# Where to put shared functions in a Python Package?

Tags: python, python-module

I'm creating a python package for internal use & it has some internal functions that are common across other modules. For example, below function is being used at other modules -

```
def GetLocalImage(WebImage):
  ImageLink = WebImage.get("data-src")
  FileName = ImageLink.split("/")[-1]
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(ImageLink,FileName)
  return(FileName)
```

As you can see the function needs to use `urllib`. Below is the file structure of the package -

```
formatter
\ __init__.py
\ File1.py    --> It would call GetLocalImage()
\ File2.py    --> It would call GetLocalImage()
```

My main program uses `from formatter import *` statement. My questions are -

1. What is the correct place for `import urllib` & the function?
2. Do I need to modify the package structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Here's how I solved it -

1. I kept the shared function to another file `common.py`
2. In the `common.py`, I've `import urllib.request`
3. In `File1.py` & `File2.py`, I've imported like `from .common import *`
4. In the main program, it's simply `import formatter`
5. In the `__init__.py` file, I've kept -

```
from .common import *
from .File1 import *
from .File2 import *
```

I think we can skip the `__init__.py` file (not sure). Hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: This technique seems neat and clear but a function in `common.py` may be imported both as `formatter.my_func` and `formatter.common.my_func`. This creates some confusion, also when building documentation (e.g. with docstring).

Comment: Yes, I agree on this.I need to check what happens if I remove the ```from .common import *``` from the ```__init__.py``` & just keep it in the ```File1.py``` or ```File2.py```

Comment: Best practices seem to avoid `from something import *` or, at least, at the beginning of your `common.py` use the `__all__ = ["YOUR_DEFINITIONS"]`.